# Generating a javascript array in php with "Foreach" Loop

Tags: php, javascript, foreach

So I'm generating a javascript array of objects in php with a `for` loop.  My code looks somewhat like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var items = [ 
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
     {
        "title" : "<?php echo $item->title ?>",
        "image" : "<?php echo $item->getImage()?>",
      }, 
 <?php  endforeach ?>
];

</script>
```

This code will not work, since I end up with an extra comma at the end of my javascript array.  Is there an elegant way to deal with that comma that separates the javascript objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
<?php
    $jsItems = array();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $jsItems[] = array(
            'title' => $item->title,
            'image' => $item->getImage()
        );
    }
    echo 'var items = '.json_encode($jsItems).';';
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that on another question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ThiefMaster's got it, but to expand on the answer:

```
$arr = array()
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $arr[] = array('title' => $item->title, 'image' => $item->getImage());
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future, in case you run into this type of looping problem again (regardless if it's json related), you can use a boolean to detect if a comma is needed:

```
<?php $firstTime = true ?>
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
    <?php 
    if (!$firstTime):
        echo ', ';
    else:
        $firstTime = false;
    endif;
    ?>
     {
        "title" : "<?php echo $item->title ?>",
        "image" : "<?php echo $item->getImage()?>",
      }
 <?php  endforeach ?>
```